# "unrecognized selector" on Monomac while creating UI elements programmatically

Tags: c#, cocoa, monomac

I am trying to create a basic RPN calculator on C#. Currently I am developing it using Monomac, as a Mac app, but I wanted to make it easier to port and develop for several platforms (I'm thinking about Android). For that purpose, rather than making all the buttons in Interface Builder, I am making everything(except the enter button, the field where the numbers are typed, and the area where the stack is shown) programmatically.

To achieve this, I made a class called `AgnosticLayout`. You can create `AgnosticLayouts` either with the `Button` function, which creates a single button that executes an action, or the `Horizontally` and `Vertically` functions, which group `AgnosticLayout`s together. The important method of this class is `Display<T>`, which, given a way to turn single operations into `T`s, and a way to group `T`s together, returns a complete layout of type `T:` so that I can describe my buttons as an `AgnosticLayout`, and each platform is able to turn it into its own kind of GUI(in the case of Mac, into an NSView).

I already was able to implement the function that turns operations into buttons, and was able to show one, but I'm struggling with joining buttons.

My current function is:

```
NSView Joiner(IEnumerable<NSView> elems, bool isLeftRight)
{
    NSView view = new NSView();
    int i = 0; // used to give a unique key to each element
    string[] keys = new string[elems.Count()];
    NSView[] elemarray = new NSView[elems.Count()]; // array of elements to be fed to NSDictionary for the constraint
    string visualformat;
    if (isLeftRight) // Creating the visual format string
    {
        visualformat = "|-0-";
    }
    else
    {
        visualformat = "V:|-0-";
    }
    foreach (NSView elem in elems)
    {
        char a = (char) (i+97);
        keys[i] = a.ToString();
        elemarray[i] = elem;
        i += 1;
        view.AddSubview(elem);
        visualformat += "[" + a.ToString() + "]-0-"; 
    }
    visualformat += "|";
    NSDictionary elemsdict = NSDictionary.FromObjectsAndKeys(keys,elemarray);
    view.AddConstraints (NSLayoutConstraint.FromVisualFormat (
        visualformat,
        NSLayoutFormatOptions.None,
        new NSDictionary (),
        elemsdict)
    );
```

This is not only ugly as fuck, but also doesn't work. I get this when I run everything:

```
2013-11-10 14:00:14.971 CalculatorMac[2006:1007] -[NSButton copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6555bc0
2013-11-10 14:00:14.972 CalculatorMac[2006:1007] -[NSButton copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6555bc0
```

I suppose this is an ObjC exception rather than a C# one, which means that Cocoa is crashing, not the program itself. I don't know what the message means.

I haven't found any useful solution in Google, mainly because most of them are for ObjC, a language I do not understand.

Relevant files:

[MainWindowController](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kl9wqis6rgzk6mo/MainWindowController.cs).

[Calculator](https://www.dropbox.com/s/z6txfe94crwz2mw/Calculator.cs): two important classes live here, `Calculator`(receives orders and keeps the stack) and `AgnosticLayout`.

The buttons being displayed are those in `Calculator.AgnosticLayout.DefaultLayout()`.

I know that the way to make unique names on `Joiner` is ugly: I don't care about that yet, and I think it's working right atm, because if don't use any constraints at all the whole still fails.

Also, I come from playing in Haskell for a lot of time, and I don't have a lot of experience with OO, so if there is a more idiomatic way to do what I want to do, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure that I see anything(not that I would know in this gibberish language;) )
but your error is coming from copying an NSButton, which doesn't adopt NSCopying...

this could happen if you are copying a button or using it as a key in a dictionary which implicitly retains it's objects and copies it's keys.

**EDIT**

your parameters are backwards here:

`NSDictionary.FromObjectsAndKeys(keys,elemarray);` should be -> 
`NSDictionary.FromObjectsAndKeys(elemarray,keys);`

so you are actually using the buttons as keys.

Comment: So I am copying a button somewhere, but buttons can't be copied. That's a clue. However, I am not copying it directly, and I don't use it as a key, but as a value: could it be possible that putting a button in an *array* copies it? (Actually, it makes a lot of sense, now that I think about it). How would I go about doing what I want to do? (given a list of buttons, making a dictionary that has them as values and a unique key for each of them).

Comment: no storing as a value in a collection class will not copy. I see the answer see edit.

Comment: Oh thank you! That was it. Such a dumb mistake. Now it's fixed(it has different problems, but I can handle them atm).

Comment: @DR6 if you are satisfied with the answer you may click the check mark... to mark as the accepted answer